# Area of a parallelogram spanned by two 4D vectors without using trigonometry

Tags: vectors, area, cross-product

In 3D, we can find the area of the parallelogram spanned by two vectors by using the cross product:

$$Area = {\vert\vec a \times \vec b\vert}$$

In 2D, we can perform a similar operation using a 2D loose analog of the cross product that fills this purpose:

$$Area = {\vert\vec a_x \times \vec b_y - \vec a_y \times \vec b_x \vert}$$

How can the same be done in 4D? I know that we can just multiply the lengths and the sine of the angle between the vectors, but is there a way to do this without using trigonometry? Are there loose analogs of the cross product in 4D that fill this purpose? Also, is there a general solution that applies to 5D, 6D, etc?

I have found some other questions on Math SE asking about the areas of parallelograms between two 3D vectors, but I haven't been able to find any information about higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ as column vectors and combine them in a $4 \times 2$ matrix $A = (\vec a, \vec b)$.  Then the area of the parallelogram spanned by  $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is
$$\sqrt{\det(A^T A)}$$

More generally, if we have $k$ vectors $v_1, \dots , v_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors is $\sqrt{\det(A^T A)}$, where $A$ is the $n \times k$ matrix $(v_1, \dots ,v_k)$.

Source: *All the Mathematics You Missed [But Need to Know for Graduate School]* by Thomas A. Garrity.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented this in my C++ code and it's much faster than the trigonometric solution. Some interesting discoveries: I noticed that $A^T A$ is a 2x2 symmetrical matrix, which reduces the complexity of calculating it. The top-left is the square length of the first vector, aka the dot product with itself ($\vec a \cdot \vec a$) and similarly the bottom-left is ($\vec b \cdot \vec b$). The non-diagonal parts are both ($\vec a \cdot \vec b$). I also noticed that the result is always a positive number.

Comment: Another way to put it is that $$Area = \sqrt{(\vec a \cdot \vec a)*(\vec b \cdot \vec b) - (\vec a \cdot \vec b)*(\vec a \cdot \vec b)}$$