# Determinant for of Area of triangle in 3D

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

As we all know that area of a triangle is given by absolute value of the determinant of this matrix$
A = \dfrac 1 2 {\left| \begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} \right|},
$ for 2D coordinates system. However is there a formula involving **determinants** for 3D Coordinates.
(Note: I know that we can use cross products of vectors to find area of triangle for 3D coordinates and that it works for general n coordinates but I wanted to know if there exists a formula for 3D in determinant form(even if its probably impractical to use it))

Comment: A cross product can be expressed as a determinant, can it not?

Comment: @Théophile firstly while taking cross products you need to do $x_2-x_1$ and similar stuff and then you need to find the magnitude of the cross product. but you cannot find the magnitude of the cross product directly using determinants and instead need to do a intermediate step of finding the vector and then finding its magnitude using square roots of sum of square of its components.

Comment: You might be interested in the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437123/area-of-a-parallelogram-spanned-by-two-4d-vectors-without-using-trigonometry/4437528#4437528

Comment: Yes, the volume of simplices can be expressed by a generalization of this determinant.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128991/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-3d-triangle